# Стилизовать последний элемент определенного класса

Tags: html, css

Можно ли при существующей разметке задать в CSS стили для последнего span'а класса "c2" внутри элемента с ID "a" (помечен восклицательным знаком)?

```
<div id = "a">
    <span class = "c1">...</span>
    <span class = "c1">...</span>
    <span class = "c2">...</span>
    <span class = "c2">...</span>!
    <span class = "c1">...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Псевдокласс `:last-child` задает стилевое оформление последнего элемента своего родителя.

Это значит, что он работает только на последний элемент, **из всех** дочерних элементов, а не на последний элемент для класса или еще какого-нибуть признака

В данном случае, лучше использовать другой псевдокласс `:nth-child()`

```
#a span:nth-child(4) /* отсчет от одного, а не от нуля! */
```

[Пример](http://jsbin.com/punirizewi/edit?html,css,output)

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#a span:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="a">
    <span class="c1">1...</span>
    <span class="c1">2...</span>
    <span class="c2">3...</span>
    <span class="c2">4...</span>
    <span class="c1">5...</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Не очень хорошо в том случае, если, как и у меня, номер необходимого элемента сразу не известен. Известно лишь то, что это последний элемент класса C2 внутри общего предка.

Comment: @nup, используйте js в таком случае, иначе ни как по другому вашу задачу не решить ( в данном случае )

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас все будет выводится динамически, то используйте jquery метод .last
[http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Поиск_последнего_элемента_в_наборе](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5)